# Custom rightBarButtonItem image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to use a custom rightBarButtonItem image using this code in my viewWillAppear method:

```
    // Custom rightBarButtonItem
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_button"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action: @selector(handleBackButton)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width - 10, buttonImage.size.height - 10)];
[view addSubview:button];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

The result is like this:

[image]

But I would like it smaller, just like I designed it in Sketch 3:

[image]

What do I need to do different to achieve this?

Thanks!
Erik

Comment: It looks like you have only provided a retina resource and are running on a non-retina device.

Comment: @lan MacDonald I'm running it on my real iPhone 5s and it has a retina display, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 5s has a retina display. I was just commenting on what it *looks* like. I'm not 100% sure what's happening here to make your image appear incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to adjust the image edge insets:

```
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, leftInset, bottomInset, rightInset)];
```

Comment: what would the different insets be?

Comment: That depends on the size of your button image, and the size of your button. Use a breakpoint or NSLog to output the width and height of your button. Set the insets such that the left and right insets added to the non-retina width of your image equals the width of your button. Similarly, the top and bottom insets added to the non-retina image height should equal the height of the button.

Comment: What exactly is an inset

Comment: You could also just experiment. Comparing the two images you provided, it looks like setting the top and bottom insets to 6, and the sides to 9 might work.

Comment: I experimentet and found 9 and 10, so we're pretty close to each other :P @Peter

Comment: An inset is like padding.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you set the rendering mode of UIIMage to **UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal** like this.

```
UIImage *barButtonimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_button"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Then you can set the image of UIBarButtonItem as following

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage: barButtonimage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)];
```

> UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal : Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template.